# Connect Bluetooth headset programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, external-accessory

I need to connect the bluetooth handset programmatically in one of my iOS projects. I do not want to go through iPhone settings to connect the bluetooth handset.

Is there any possibility to achieve this in iOS SDK via public API?

If not then how can I achieve this via private frameworks?

Comment: You can't do that. Only bluetooth low energy devices can be freely managed by the applications. I haven't researched private frameworks.

Comment: Besides BLE not having enough throughput for audio streaming; even with BLE, Apple hides certain profiles from applications (example: HID service).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with public iOS APIs.

Regarding private frameworks: There is the [BluetoothManager](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager.h) framework. I have not experimented with it too heavily yet, though.